# System returning name of class instead of variable

Tags: powershell, passwords, securestring, write-host

I have a small PowerShell script I'm writing that allows me to grab a user from Active Directory and randomly generate a password for them.

```
$Alphabet=$NULL
for ($a=48; $a –le 70; $a++) {
    $Alphabet += ,[char][byte]$a
}

function Get-TempPassword() {
    Param (
        [int]$Length=10,
        [string[]]$Source
    )

    for ($loop=1; $loop –le $length; $loop++) {
        $TempPassword += ($Source | Get-Random) 
    }
    return $TempPassword
}

$Password = Get-TempPassword -Length 10 -Source $Alphabet
$NewPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force

Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $User -NewPassword $NewPassword
Set-ADUser –Identity $User –ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
Unlock-ADAccount $User | Out-Null

$Name = (Get-ADUser $User -Properties Name).Name
Write-Host "Okay, $Name's new password has been set to '$NewPassword'."
```

Instead of the last line returning

> Okay, User's new password has been set to '[Password]'.

it's returning

> Okay, User's new password has been set to 'System.Security.SecureString'.

I believe it's returning that class and not setting that as the password because I can't log in with that as a password for the user. I assume I'm overlooking something, but I've stared at it for quite some time now and can't see what I'm missing. I've also tried commenting out the line

```
$NewPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
```

and it doesn't seem to help, which I expected to error out because the variables no longer match.

Comment: You can't print a securestring to the screen directly

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman, I wasn't sure how to word my problem and couldn't find another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you are making a password:

```
$Password = Get-TempPassword -Length 10 -Source $Alphabet
```

Then you turn it into a Secure String

```
$NewPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
```

So if you want to see the password, then output `$Password` rather than the secure string `$NewPassword`

```
Write-Host "Okay, $Name's new password has been set to '$Password'."
```

Comment: As BenH said, you cant see the secure string. It's by design. In other words, print out the `$password` before you convert it to a secure string.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks a lot. I would mark this as Best Answer, but I think it's too soon after the post and there is no option to :)

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, then you should accept the answer.